# Background image not showing in winforms

Tags: vb.net, winforms

[**Check this link**](http://bytes.com/topic/visual-basic-net/answers/433169-backgroundimage-will-not-display) this is exactly what my problem is..

[image]

At Form_Load:

```
Me.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.black_gradient_background
```

I even deleted back color property at designer, it reverted to default, but..

still...
[image]
But the image is there, I can see it when loading the form, then it disappears, its like in the back. Why is that? I tried to create new form, added that background image, its working fine. What did I do? >.<

**UPDATE** I tried Restarting VS, did it to another form. look what happened:
[image]
The BGimage only appeared on the left groupBox. O_o

Comment: I think BackColor may be a problem

Comment: I think, I did use back color at first, then I changed my mind, so instead, I used a gradient picture, now its not showing.

Comment: image appears in the Preview box??

Comment: yup, in the control tab, check up there. But not in the design view, but a glimpse in form load then the next picture you see is that.

Comment: try restarting visual Studio, maybe it works

Comment: Me.BackgroundImage = Image.My.Resources.black_gradient_background

Comment: Or restart your visual studio

Comment: Restarted it, update question. see what happened O_o

Comment: BackgroundImageLayout Property choose none

Comment: You completely overlapped it with other controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Hans says you are blocking the image with other controls, you need to set the other controls that you want the image to show through as transparent `Control.BackColor = Color.Transparent`.

Comment: I have solved it that day though. When I recolored my Form, I didn't know that it also colored the group boxes. I just made them into transparent then.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing form layout from RtoL to LtoR